# Programmatically preprocess picture for parsing to OCR

Tags: java, image, tess4j

I have an image where I crop on the region that I have set to recognize by ocr using tesseract. After all the image processing the result is like this
[image: Image before processing]

When this image is given to do ocr, the result is not accurate like

> Image 7_B7.bmp = W’ I
>   WTH 3795 ’
>   _/ 7777777777” f ‘
>   .1.“ we)? 1

What I want to do is to make the image to be like this(edited in paint)
[image: Expected result of preprocessing]

so that it will give more accurate result after recognition. What can I do to get image like this?

Comment: Does Tesseract give you a position and confidence value?